# MySQL tmp tables: how to clean up diskspace after killing a copying to tmp table process?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, innodb, disk-space-utilization

i ran out of disk space while running an alter table on a large table. I restarted MySQL afterwards and checked the MySQL tmp dir. A show status like '%tmp%' lists 5 tmp files and 4 tmp tables. A df still shows 99% disk usage (was like 72% before the alter table).

Running a "check table" returns "OK".

How to clean up the disk space used by the alter table command?

I'm running MySQL 5.5.31 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks: Lars

Comment: you can use some ram partition for `tmptable` instead of hdd, this can be better for space and performance

Comment: Unfortunately the server only has 8 GB ram and i assume MySQL needs like 20 GB to complete the alter table process.

Answer (score 0):

Common approach to find where your space has gone.

1. check for explicit files disk usage with `du -ms /path/*`.
2. check "hidden" open files disk usage with `lsof | grep deleted | grep /path`
3. last resort: check the file-system consistency.

Comment: I just mentioned InnoDB in the tags, sorry. There are no tmp files, it's just InnoDB's ibdata file that now is 40 GB.

Comment: Ok in that case a usefull link for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456159/how-to-shrink-purge-ibdata1-file-in-mysql